# Inventor of FTL drive is granted ownership of an Earthlike planet. Native species prevents destruction of life

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, animals

I am looking for a Sci Fi book I read many years ago. The synopsis is as follows:

- A guy discovered FTL drive or something and would share the secret under one condition. He was to be granted ownership of a new planet of his choosing. The planet would be very similar to Earth in topography.
- He wanted to remake the new planet for a place where Earth's declining animal species could be revived.
- He got the planet and started introducing animal species, including fish and water mammals.
- When one of the carnivorous cats (cheetah I believe), got sick from eating grass, he discovered that there was another species there that revered and would not allowed life to be destroyed.
- A compromise was worked out and everything was OK.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.